# Android Studio: Link of external JAR in a multi modules project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar

I have an Android application (running on Android Studio). It is made of 2 modules:
-   There is a low level pure java module (let’s call it module A). 
-   On top of it, there is the module B which is the Android application. It relies on moduleA for some processings.

This is working fine.

I now need the module A to call an external Library. I have downloaded the JAR file and put it in moduleA/libs folder. 
This libs folder is referenced in gradle dependency of moduleA so the compilation is OK. However, there is an exception at runtime:

FATAL EXCEPTION Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "XXXX" on path: DexPathList

I have seen that the APK doesn’t contain the JAR file so it is normal that this exception occurs.

If I copy the same JAR file in moduleB/libs, then it works fine but I have the JAR file two times in the project! What is the clean solution to handle this?
I guess that it can be solved with gradle but I don't know how.

Thank you very much
Olivier

Comment: Converting jar library to aar is workaround: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/including-a-java-project-into-an-android-library-project-does-not-include-transitive-file-dependencies/2442/8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been able to fix this issue. This reading about Gradle helped me a lot:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-Library-Project

Here is what I have done:
Instead of putting the JAR file in moduleA/libs folder, I have imported the JAR file in Android Studio by clicking on the project then right click -> new -> module. I then clicked on “Import .JAR/.AAR package”.
This created a module containing the JAR file + a gradle script.

Then, in moduleA’s gradle script, I have added this in the dependencies:
  compile project(path: ':name_of_the_jar_file')

I rebuilt all and it works. The JAR file is now present in the APK and there is no more crash at runtime.