# Import module to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm tryin to import a Java module from Intellij IDEA to my Android Studio. The module provides certain functionalliy for creating pdf documents.

Now, the Android Studio won't let me to import this module because it is built by Gradle.

I would like to know how can I integrate my module to my existing Android Studio project. Furthermore, I'd like to know what are those .iml files in the root directory of the project.

Comment: .iml files are configuration files by IDE. What build is your project, is it not gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You could build the jar dependency from your module in IntelliJ IDEA and [include this jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956456/104891) into the `build.gradle` dependencies. There is also [another way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440077/104891).

`.iml` files represent module information. Your module was of the Java type and Android Studio doesn't support plain Java modules, therefore there is no direct way to import it.